# Slicing across a timeseries range in a multiindex DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice

I have a DataFrame that tracks the 'Adj Closing' price for several global markets causing there to be repeating dates. To clean this up I use `.set_index(['Index Ticker', 'Date'])`.

[DataFrame sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3dUY.png)

My issue is that the Closing Prices run as far back as 1997-07-02 but I only need 2020-01-01 and forward. I tried using `idx = pd.IndexSlice` followed by `df.loc[idx[ :, '2020-01-01':], :]` as well as `df.loc[(slice(None), '2020-01-01':), :]`, but both methods return a syntax error on the `:` that I'm using to slice across a range of dates. Any tips on getting the data I need past a specific date? Thank you in advance!

Comment: It's hard to say without some sample data. But I think this one `df.loc[idx[ :, '2020-01-01':]. :]` the dot (`.`) should've been a comma `df.loc[idx[ :, '2020-01-01':], :]`

Comment: Sorry about that, that was just a typo. I've corrected that to a comma, still the same issue trying to slice across a specific range of dates. Added a picture of the actual dataframe I'm trying to slice so that I get the same columns, but none of the values before '2020-01-01'

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
# create dataframe to approximate your data
df = pd.DataFrame({'ticker' : ['A']*5 + ['M']*5, 
                   'Date' : pd.date_range(start='2021-01-01', periods=5).tolist() + pd.date_range(start='2021-01-01', periods=5).tolist(),
                   'high' : range(10)}
                 ).groupby(['ticker', 'Date']).sum()

                   high
ticker Date
A      2021-01-01     0
       2021-01-02     1
       2021-01-03     2
       2021-01-04     3
       2021-01-05     4
M      2021-01-01     5
       2021-01-02     6
       2021-01-03     7
       2021-01-04     8
       2021-01-05     9

# evaluate conditions against level 1 (Date) of your multiIndex; level 0 is ticker
df[df.index.get_level_values(1) > '2021-01-03']

                  high
ticker Date
A      2021-01-04     3
       2021-01-05     4
M      2021-01-04     8
       2021-01-05     9
```

Alternatively, if possible, remove the unwanted dates prior to setting your multiIndex.